# Wrong results when comparing two numbers with bc (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, bc

I’ve encountered an error, probably a bug in [`bc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bc). I encountered it when trying to compare two numbers on a script in bash. It turns out that when I do:

```
echo "1.1E-2<1.1E-1" | bc -l
```

It returns 1 (as expected).

But when I do this for exmaple:

```
echo "2.1E-2<1.1E-1" | bc -l
```

It returns 0, when it should return 1 (because 0.021 is smaller than 0.11).

I’m using bc version 1.06.95 with kubuntu 14.04

Has anyone found a similar result? Can anyone think of a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

`bc` doesn't understand exponential notation.

It probably interprets "E" as a hex digit, but in longer numbers, it seems to translate it to 9 (bug?), and similarly for other hex digits:

```
bc -l <<< E-4    # 14 - 4
10

bc -l <<< 1E-1   # 19 - 1
18

bc -l <<< F.4E2
9.492
```

Answer (score 1):

Your workaround

```
    echo "2.1*10^-2<1.1*10^-1" | bc -l
```

If the case you want to transform the output of another file you can do something similar to

```
    echo "2.1E-2<1.1E-1" | sed 's/E/*10^/g'  | bc -l
```

where with `sed` you go to substitute `E` with `*10^` that is accepted by `bc`